# Firmware upload

Tags: diy-3d-printer, firmware

I have a 3d printer without a firmware. It's a Wanhao Duplicator I3. 
I try to upload a version, but I have a little problem, at uploading on melzi board, it's a V03 version. 
I try this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejpSniiJejI [image]

Comment: You have to be careful when compiling Repetier-Firmware, since successful compilation is dependent of using the correct version of Arduino Studio. What version of Repetier-Firmware are you trying to compile?

Comment: In any case, you have a compilation problem, not an upload problem. That will come later.

Comment: You are not bound to use Repetier firmware, you can also use Marlin firmware, I've read that more than 3/4 of all printers use Marlin, this has a larger fan base and as such more people to help you out. Note you have a segmentation fault as a result of your code changes, these are pretty hard to debug anyways, so starting fresh might be a good idea.